# How to do unit test in multi-module maven projects?

Tags: java, rest, maven, unit-testing

I have a multi-module maven project. Where module A is a web module and provides restful api for other modules. Module B is a client module and many classes of module B invoke restful api from module A with http-client. My question is how to do auto unit test for the classes in module B.

Client A request server B with async http. The client request brings some message like version and so on, if there is data newer than the given version, the server will response with new data right now. Otherwise the request will be hanged on till timeout or newer data is available. I want to test this interaction. A and B are in the same Java project. Can I dependence module A in B with test scope and mock a 'real' server with the code in module A?

Comment: You'll be needing a mocking framework such as (shameless plug) Mockito.

Comment: Can you explain exactly where you are stuck? Give an example of what code you want to unit test and explain what you are uncertain about.

Comment: Client A request server B with async http. The client request brings some message like version and so on, if there is data newer than the given version, the server will response with  new data right now. Otherwise the request will be hanged on till timeout or newer data is available. I want to test this interaction. A and B are in the same Java project. Can I dependence module A in B with test scope and mock  a 'real' server with the code in module A?

Comment: @denghuichao Why does your comment copy verbatim from your question?